# Understanding FFT operations in Python code snippet

Tags: python, fft

I came across this snippet of code in a program that does real time FFT graph of audio data:

```
data=scipy.array(struct.unpack("%dB"%(bufferSize*2),data))
ffty=scipy.fftpack.fft(data)
ffty=abs(ffty[0:len(ffty)/2])/1000
ffty1=ffty[:len(ffty)/2]
ffty2=ffty[len(ffty)/2::]+2                
ffty2=ffty2[::-1]                
ffty=ffty1+ffty2                              
ffty=scipy.log(ffty)-2
```

I didn't understand the math behind the part after the `abs()`. It does something like adding the first half of the magnitude array with the second half reversed, and 2 added.

Is this some kind of normalization?

This is the source:

http://www.swharden.com/blog/2010-03-05-realtime-fft-graph-of-audio-wav-file-or-microphone-input-with-python-scipy-and-wckgraph/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Python but it looks like it's just adding the magnitude of the two mirror image complex conjugate halves of the real-to-complex FFT output. You could just as easily take only the magnitude of the first half and multiply by 2.

Finally it computes the log magnitude, presumably to get (scaled) dB values.

Comment: Well the log gets you to scaled dB magnitude, but since dB values are arbitrary without some sort of 0 dB reference I guess the -2 is just to get to the required range for plotting/display.

Comment: It grabs the non-negative frequencies in the `abs` expression, but it has a one-off error. The non-negative frequency part needs to be length N//2+1. I guess it cuts off the last sample in order to have an even length vector for the next part. For some reason, I have no idea why, it adds two to the upper half of the expression (starting at pi/2 radians/sample), reverses it and adds it to the lower half of the spectrum.

Comment: Also, one can't simply double all of the non-negative frequency components. That would double the value of 0 and pi radians/sample, which are already at the correct value (i.e. they aren't split into conjugates). Also, a component at pi radians/sample is only present if N is even.

Comment: I overlooked the `unpack`, which is even more confused, but somewhat explains the spectrum folding. He's doubling the vector length by unpacking `int16` values as unsigned bytes ('B'). He shouldn't be using `struct.unpack` with NumPy/SciPy at all. But if he does, it needs to be unpacked to `signed short` (format 'h'). Instead, use `np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)` to have NumPy use the data buffer directly instead of copying arrays in memory.

Comment: @eryksun - thanks, I am actually using struct.unpack with "%dh" in my code - didn't understand why "%dB" was used above. I guess that might explain some of the operations above. I'll switch to frombuffer().

Comment: @M-V: To save some CPU cycles you can use `np.fft.rfft` to compute just the non-negative frequency components from 0 to `2 * pi / N * (N // 2)`, inclusive, in `N // 2 + 1` bins ('//' is Python's floor division operator). If N is even, as is common (typically a power of 2 for efficiency in a radix-2 fft), the range is 0 to pi radians/sample in N/2 + 1 bins. For consistency, divide the first bin (and last bin, only if N is even) by 2.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks, I had tried rfft once - still trying to understand all this. Why do we divide the first and last bins by 2? The first is the DC component, isn't it?

Comment: Could we please [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19736/discussion-between-m-v-and-eryksun)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that audio sound comes in stereo file format, and this is a averaging over left/right canal. I'm saying so because of this line : `fftx=fftx[0:len(fftx)/4]` which is a common operation when using stereo signals.

However I don't know why a canal is raised.